# How to put a child node in a child node of a child node

Tags: c#

```
TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode("Course");

node1.Text = "Course";
node1.Nodes.Add("BSCS");
node1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("BS301E");
```

How can I add 3 child nodes to BS301E? Hope you could help me with a very simple code.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can write extension method to simplify a code. F.e.:

```
public static StaticClassForExtensionMethod
{
    public static AddRange(this ICollection<Node> nodes, params string[] names)
    {
        foreach (var name in names)
            nodes.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Now you can call the method as if it's a method of the `ICollection<Node>` interface:

```
node1.Nodes[0].Nodes.AddRange("1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: Your `AddRange` method does not specify a return type (or void).  Also, I don't think this answers the question.  This adds all nodes to the same parent.  The OP wants to add a child node and then another node to that child.

Answer (score 0):

The `Add` method of the Nodes collection returns the node that was just added.  So just store that in a variable so you can reference it later.

```
TreeNode courseNode = new TreeNode("Course");
courseNode.Text = "Course";

//bscsNode is the child of courseNode    
TreeNode bscsNode = courseNode.Nodes.Add("BSCS");

//bs301ENode is the child of bscsNode
TreeNode bs301ENode = bscsNode.Nodes.Add("BS301E");
```

Comment: Or, more concisely: `return new TreeNode("Course").Nodes.Add("BSCS").Nodes.Add("BS301E")`